# FIRApp.Configure Crashing App

Tags: swift, firebase

I am using Xcode and Swift. My application keeps crashing and saying "The default app has not been configured yet." But I do have it configuring in my appDelegate. Has anyone encountered this issue?[image: screenshot]

Comment: please do not use images to show code. add it as text, much easier to analyze. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use the `override init()` method in the AppDelegate to configure Firebase. The Firebase documentation shows the configuration in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method but I haven't gotten that approach to work in my apps.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    override init() {
        FIRApp.configure()
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: @CoderCody Please accept the answer if it worked for you. Thanks.

Comment: Just waiting on the timer to run out lol I have 2 more minutes before I can accept a answer:P